# how to fetch row attribute values in foreachpartition

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying

```
def customFunction(rows):
    for row in rows:
        key = row.key #this value is boolean instead of actual value same with row["key"]
        val = row.value #this value is boolean instead of actual value same with row["val"]
        #do something with key value

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL Hive integration example") \
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouse_location) \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()


# spark is an existing SparkSession
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS src (key INT, value STRING) USING hive")
spark.sql("LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'examples/src/main/resources/kv1.txt' INTO TABLE src")

# Queries are expressed in HiveQL
df = spark.sql("SELECT key, value FROM src")

# assumption that df row size is of billions
df.rdd.foreachPartition(customFunction)
```

I am getting booelan values in key, val variables in custom function. How do we fetch the row attribute actual values?

This is run on aws emr 5.29, python 2.7, python code is executed via spark-submit

Comment: Yep, deserved the downvote.  What I am trying is pyspark equivalent of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421593/task-not-serializable-when-trying-to-write-record-from-spark-dataframe-to-dynamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case if this helps, inside `customFunction` I was trying to use value `key` into dynamodb and it was storing a boolean value when key was NULL.